# node.js module not found in subfolder

Tags: node.js, express, puppeteer

I am building a basic web scraper using node, express, and puppeteer, and when I try to run node index.js. I get this error

```html
alexskreen@Alexs-MacBook-Air WOD-Scraper2 % node server/index.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './server/scrapers'
Require stack:
- /Users/alexskreen/Desktop/WOD-Scraper2/server/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/alexskreen/Desktop/WOD-Scraper2/server/index.js:8:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/Users/alexskreen/Desktop/WOD-Scraper2/server/index.js' ]
}
```

Before adding my require statements everything is working:

```js
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const scrapers = require('./server/scrapers');
const db = require('./server/db');
```

Comment: Are you sure you have installed "scrapers" package ? if it is your custom module then you should add relative path as well. ( ../ - for parent directory).

Answer (score 0):

If module is in your subfolder you should use,

```js
const something = require("./subfolder/module");
```

If it is not a subfolder module then make sure it is installed in **node_modules**.

Comment: My mistake, I pasted the wrong snippet. I originally had require statements written like this: const something = require("./module");